# While creating new event trying to save event id to the user who created it...errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, events

I have an application that deals with events. User need to be logged in to create events, when they do create an event I need to add the event ID to the user.events array. However I am running into difficulty saving events to the users, this is the main issue. I get  my other data in my 'events' route that is being redirected to after the event is created.

```
router.post("/event",  isLoggedIn, function (req,res){
// get data from form and add to events array
var title = req.body.title;
var date =  req.body.date;
var description = req.body.description;
var venue = req.body.venue;
var photo = req.body.photo;
var category = req.body.category;
//get user data to save to the event.
var owner = {
    id: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
}
var newEvent = {category: category, title: title, date: date, description: description, venue: venue, photos:{link: photo,date: date}, owner: owner};
Event.create(newEvent, function(err, event){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        //This takes the event owner ID and saves it into the Event model
        //event.owner.id = req.user._id;
        //This takes the event username and saves it into the Event model
        event.owner.username = req.user.username;
        event.save();
        //console.log(event);
        //Save the event ID in the user document
        User.update({_id: event.owner.id}, function(err,savedData){
            savedData.events = {eventId:  event._id};
            savedData.save();

        })
        //Add the Event ID to the User model
        console.log (owner);
    }
});
res.redirect('events');

})
```

In my model I have User.events as an array, I am not sure if that is an issue, but the error I get is on the redirect to 'events' it tells me that events.forEach is not a function.

Here is the line in the template that is creating the error:

```
 <% events.forEach(function(events){ %>
```

Here is the 'events' route:

```
router.get("/events",  isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
User.findById(req.user._id).populate("moments").populate("events").exec(function(err,allEvents){
    console.log("The id of the user " + req.user._id)
    console.log("User ID: " + req.user._id)
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Ummm.... the database may be down?.......")
    } else {
        // if (allEvents === null){
        //     res.redirect("/dashboard");
        //     console.log("nothing in AllEvents");
        //     console.log(allEvents);
        // } else {
        console.log("Below are all the events pulled");
        //console.log(allEvents)
        res.render("eventsList", {events: allEvents});
       // }
    }
})
});
```

Comment: If your error is in the 'events' route handler, then you should post that instead or in addition to what you've already posted.

Comment: Thank you, posted more detail.

Comment: What does your `console.log(allEvents)` show and/or what does `console.log(typeof allEvents)` show? If the latter displays 'object', what does `console.log(Array.isArray(allEvents))` show?

Comment: allEvents I get: 
{ __v: 0,
  title: 'asdf',
  description: 'asdfasdf',
  _id: 583baec0b516ab29acfcbff8,
  comments: [],
  photos: { link: '', date: null },
  moments: [],
  category: [ 'asdf' ],
  owner: { id: 5835f632487e976108ccc15e, username: 'asdf' } }
{ id: 5835f632487e976108ccc15e, username: 'asdf' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allEvents` is a plain object, not an Array, so `forEach()` and other Array-related methods are not available.

If you want to iterate over the properties of the object, you could instead do `Objects.keys(allEvents).forEach(function(key) {` and use `allEvents[key]` to get the value for each key. Otherwise, just completely remove the `events.forEach(function(events){` (and the associated `}`).

Comment: So you cannot iterate over objects with `forEach` I did not know that, still learning here obviously.

Should this code go into Node or into the ejs template? I see you have `Objects.keys(allEvents)` what does that do? Does that create an array of the objects?
For clarification what would the actual code look like without using the placeholders, I am confused by them. Thanks.

Comment: I found a really good example of Objects.keys(). [link](https://davidwalsh.name/object-keys), your example is very good mscdex, sorry I didnt pick up what you were putting down right away!